# Hi there is an error in my code using Adafruit fona and GSM on Arduino Uno. My void loop() has error it it sending me this error:

Tags: arduino, char, gsm, adafruit

> here is the error: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
> if (!fona.sendSMS(callerIDbuffer, "Hey, I got your text!")) {
> i am using arduino and adafruit fona by the way, any one who wants to help is very much appreciated

*here is my code*

```
void loop() {
  
   char* bufPtr = fonaNotificationBuffer;    //handy buffer pointer
  
  if (fona.available())      //any data available from the FONA?
  {
    int slot = 0;            //this will be the slot number of the SMS
    int charCount = 0;
    //Read the notification into fonaInBuffer
    do  {
      *bufPtr = fona.read();
      Serial.write(*bufPtr);
      delay(1);
    } while ((*bufPtr++ != '\n') && (fona.available()) && (++charCount < (sizeof(fonaNotificationBuffer)-1)));
    
    //Add a terminal NULL to the notification string
    *bufPtr = 0;

    //Scan the notification string for an SMS received notification.
    //  If it's an SMS message, we'll get the slot number in 'slot'
    if (1 == sscanf(fonaNotificationBuffer, "+CMTI: " FONA_PREF_SMS_STORAGE ",%d", &slot)) {
      Serial.print("slot: "); Serial.println(slot);
      
      char callerIDbuffer[32];  //we'll store the SMS sender number in here
      
      // Retrieve SMS sender address/phone number.
      if (! fona.getSMSSender(slot, callerIDbuffer, 31)) {
        Serial.println("Didn't find SMS message in slot!");
      }
      Serial.print(F("FROM: ")); Serial.println(callerIDbuffer);
    
        // Retrieve SMS value.
        uint16_t smslen;
        if (fona.readSMS(slot, smsBuffer, 250, &smslen)) { // pass in buffer and max len!
          Serial.println(smsBuffer);
        }

      //Send back an automatic response
      Serial.println("Sending reponse...");
      if (!fona.sendSMS(callerIDbuffer, "Hey, I got your text!")) {
        Serial.println(F("Failed"));
      } else {
        Serial.println(F("Sent!"));
      }
      
      // delete the original msg after it is processed
      //   otherwise, we will fill up all the slots
      //   and then we won't be able to receive SMS anymore
      if (fona.deleteSMS(slot)) {
        Serial.println(F("OK!"));
      } else {
        Serial.print(F("Couldn't delete SMS in slot ")); Serial.println(slot);
        fona.print(F("AT+CMGD=?\r\n"));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

> i think theres an error in char but i can't solve it

Answer (score 0):

It's just crappy library that doesn't use `const char *` for C string parameters that won't get changed inside of functions. It's old school C style approach in C++.

Also it should be reported just as a warning, not an error. Now you have two options - fix that library or ignore this warning. I don't like the second option, but it'll be the easiest way for you (but it's not a good thing to ignore warnings, sometimes they might be realy on point of some nasty bug).

Comment: should i download the old library?

Comment: If it works, you don't have to. But wouldn't expect any older version to have const correctness and later one doesn't